# see if the user is on mobile then excute javaquery?

Tags: javascript, javaquery

i was wondering if there is away for my website check if the user is using a mobile browser then if the user is to execute javaquery, and if not to use normal JavaScript

Comment: First, you have to define what is a "mobile browser".

Comment: You can use the [isMobile](https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile) library

Comment: Maybe this is related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery?rq=1

Comment: there are multiple ways you can detect whether something is "mobile":
- screen size
- touch events
- modernizr (hidden scrollbar)
- browser agent
you'll have to be more specific to what your definition of "mobile browser" is!

Answer (score 0):

See: http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-mobile-devices-jquery/

Basically this should work:

```
if(jQuery.browser.mobile)
{
   console.log('You are using a mobile device!');
}
```